# In Maigret's Dead Man episode, why is he asked to file the case closed?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, maigret

In the second **Maigret** episode, season 1 from ITV staring **Rowan Atkinson**, we see Maigret asked by his colleague to file the report and close the case on the dead man thrown from the car for being too **Underworld**.

What is meant by this? Surely a case such a this, or at least what they did warranted a bit of a push at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Too Underworld" means that the crime is perpetrated by criminals against *other criminals* rather than innocent citizens being victimized.

The primary case that Maigret is being asked to investigate instead is the vicious assault and murder of innocent citizens in Picardie.

Alternatively, the case that Maigret prefers *appears* to be underworld related although Maigret is not convinced.

In fact, it was made to look that way **because** the criminals know that the police will take it less seriously and only conduct a cursory investigation.

The victim's friend tells Maigret...

> "The police don't take much interest if a gangster's found dead in the street. You don't sniff around that for long.
>
> "So we dumped him like it was an underworld hit."

Maigret feels that this impression is false (clearly) but his superiors / senior colleague don't see it *and* have other priorities.

Of course, none of the investigators realise  that the two investigations are *connected* until the end.